# How can I autosize columns after data loaded in kendo-grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I see from kendo documentation for angular kendo-grid that there is an [autofitcolumn method](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-autofitcolumns).

The example shows how to apply this via a button on the interface.  What I am looking to do is see if there is a way to autofit columns whenever data is loaded into the kendo-grid.

I tried adding a call to the method after my data is returned in my component like this:

```
        this.busy = this.service.query(URL, this.state)
        .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
        .subscribe(resp => {
            // console.log('resp', resp);
            this.view = resp;
            this.k-grid.autoFitColumns() //auto-fit
        }, err => {
            console.error(`error: ${err}`);
            this.authService.handleError(err);
        });
```

But the autofit call is running before the data is actually loaded in the k-grid, so no resizing happens.

The k-grid also dosen't have a on-data-loaded event or anything like that (that I have found) that I could hook into.

In a perfect world there would be a setting to pass in to do this for me, or a data loaded event that I could hook into.

How do I get columns autosized after data load?

Comment: Have you tried adding width: 100% to the columns in question?

Comment: Tried adding this, but it did not cause the columns to resize.

Answer (score 2):

Call the autoFitColumns() method once the data is received from the back-end and should be nested within a timeout function.

Get the grid control into the component as below

```
 @ViewChild('grid') grid: any;
```

and call autoFitColumns as below after you receive data from backend.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
                    this.grid.autoFitColumns();
                });


constructor(private service: CategoriesService) {
    this.view = service;
    this.service.query(this.state);
    this.view.subscribe(res =>{
      if(res){
        this.data = res;
        setTimeout(()=>{
          this.grid.autoFitColumns();
        })
      }
    })

}
```

Comment: But there will be an UI issue and grid will be rendered twice, without auto fit  columns and with auto fit columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
function AutoFitColumns(grid) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
        if (!grid.columns[i].headerAttributes.class && grid.columns[i].headerAttributes.class !== "fixed-width") {
            grid.autoFitColumn(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a way to size the columns, but my problem is detecting when the grid is loaded to execute this.

Comment: Cant you use the dataBound event on the grid? Or use the request end event and check for the type in the function.

Comment: A co-worker did find a solution that appears to work, though we are not sure why. in our data subscription, we bind the response data directly to the grid and then autosize. This appears to work. ` .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe) .subscribe(resp => { this.view = resp; this.kgrid.data = this.view; this.kgrid.autoFitColumns(); })

Answer (score 0):

You can get a reference to the Grid via ViewChild and call the **autoFitColumns()** method when the Grid is rendered (for example - in the **ngAfterViewInit** method):

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
     <kendo-grid
         #grid
         [data]="gridData"
         [resizable]="true"
         style="height: 300px">
         <kendo-grid-column-group title="Product Info">
             <kendo-grid-column
                 #firstColumn
                 field="ProductID"
                 [width]="50"
                 [minResizableWidth]="30"
                 title="ID">
             </kendo-grid-column>

             <kendo-grid-column
                 field="ProductName"
                 title="Product Name"
                 >
             </kendo-grid-column>
         </kendo-grid-column-group>

         <kendo-grid-column
             #lastColumn
             field="UnitPrice"
             title="Unit Price"
             [width]="180"
             filter="numeric"
             format="{0:c}">
         </kendo-grid-column>
     </kendo-grid>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
   @ViewChild('grid') private grid;
   public gridData: any[] = products;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.grid.autoFitColumns();
   }

}

const products = [{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "Chai",
   "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
   "Discontinued": true
 }, {
   "ProductID": 2,
   "ProductName": "Chang",
   "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
   "Discontinued": false
 }
];
```

Comment: apparently for me, afterviewinit is hit, before the kendo grid is rendered on the page.

Comment: *edit... That actually is not the issue with me using this.  When I use this, I get a ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked Error.

Comment: Indeed, changing values that are used in the DOM can cause this error. The most straight-forward approach is to wrap the call to autoFitColumns method in a setTimeout to ensure it will be performed in the next "tick" of the Angular change detection cycle:

ngAfterViewInit() {
     setTimeout(() => this.grid.autoFitColumns());
   }

Comment: followed your suggestion and wrapping it in set timeout.  The result is that the first column now takes up about 85 to 90% of the screen width...

Comment: A co-worker did find a solution that appears to work, though we are not sure why.  in our data subscription, we bind the response data directly to the grid and then autosize.  This appears to work. ` `.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            .subscribe(resp => {
                this.view = resp;
                this.kgrid.data = this.view;
                this.kgrid.autoFitColumns();
            });`